# Windows question closed as duplicate of Linux

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions

[How to reorder the files of a FAT32 file system?](https://superuser.com/questions/376577/how-to-reorder-the-files-of-a-fat32-file-system)

This question was closed as duplicate; however this does not make sense. The closed question is for Windows, and the supposed duplicates are both tagged Linux. Please reopen this valid question, thank you.

Comment: Good spot! I agree the listed duplicates are irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Makes sense. Reopened. Edited out the possible dupe text, though I wonder if it would be handy as a comment